# wordpress post formats

Tags: post-formats

i did my best to solve this problem of post formats not showing but i couln't i have checked my screen options and i have added theme support to my functions.php :

```
<?php

$ver = wp_get_theme()->get('Version');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () use ($ver) {
    // style
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-style', get_theme_file_uri('/asset/css/main.css'), array(), $ver, 'all');

    // javascript
    wp_enqueue_script('theme-script', get_theme_file_uri('/asset/js/main.js'), array(), $ver, true);
});



add_action('after_setup_theme', function() {
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    add_theme_support('menus');
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_theme_support('custom-background');
    add_theme_support('custom-header');
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery', 'link ', 'image', 'quote', 'status', 'video', 'audio', 'chat' ) );
    

    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => 'Desctop primary left sidebar',
        'footer' => 'Footer menu items'
    ));
});
?>
```

Comment: Not showing up where? In archive pages or the home page, or in the admin site?

Comment: in admin site when i want to create posts